.net from application Thread Broken error
İ have been trying to make application to reed data from serial(baudrate 9600) and write to a text box than write the same data to graph but it wont work. it either doesn't do anything or the application froze until my RAM runs out and from what i can see moment i connect to my arduino(i checked with arduino İDE it sends the data correctly) my ram usage goes from 32-50 to 1gb and internet doesn't have any solution i couldn't  even find the same problem
here's my code
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;


namespace ArduinoSerial_Teknofest_
{
    public partial class ArduinoSerial : Form
    {

        #region public veriables
        public class Globals
        {
            public static Boolean Connected = false;
            public static Boolean İfDisconnected = false;
        }

        /// To write information to console 
        public void WriteToConsole(string messege, string TextColor)
        {
            ConsoleLogs.SelectionColor = Color.FromName(TextColor);
            ConsoleLogs.SelectedText += "/// " + messege + Environment.NewLine;
        }



        #endregion

        public ArduinoSerial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Get a list of serial port names.

            PortsCB.Items.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
            //DataCharts.Series
        }

        private void ArduinoSerial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { /*
            //Get the resulation of screen
            System.Drawing.Rectangle ScreenResulation = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;

            //Set size of form to 50% of screen size
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(Convert.ToInt32(0.5 * ScreenResulation.Width),Convert.ToInt32(0.5 * ScreenResulation.Height));

            this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
          */
        }

        public void Scan_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get a list of serial port names.
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            PortsCB.Items.Clear();
            PortsCB.Items.AddRange(ports);
            WriteToConsole("Found PORTS = ", "Green");
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                WriteToConsole(port, "Green");
            }
        }
        public void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string SelectedBaudRate = BaudRateCB.Text;
           string SelectedPort = PortsCB.Text;
            if (Device.IsOpen == false)
            {
                ///Try to open the port if cant give an error
                try
                {
                    ///Get user info
                    Device.BaudRate = int.Parse(SelectedBaudRate);
                    Device.PortName = SelectedPort;
                    Device.Open();
                    ///Check if the port open, if it is disable user input bloccks
                    if (Device.IsOpen == true)
                    {
                        ConnectButton.Text = "Disconnect";
                        BaudRateCB.Enabled = false;
                        PortsCB.Enabled = false;
                        DataMenu.Enabled = true;
                        WriteToConsole("Connected", "green");
                        Device.Write("get/device/info");
                        
                    }
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException) { WriteToConsole("Something went wrong", "red"); }
                ///if post is used by other program output a error
                catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    WriteToConsole("port busy", "red");
                    Device.Close();
                }
                ///if port is allready open output an error
                catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    WriteToConsole("Port is already open", "red");
                    Device.Close();
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
                {
                    if (PortsCB.Text == "" && BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port and baudrate", "red"); }
                    else if (PortsCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port", "red"); }
                    else if (BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a baudrate", "red"); }
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentException)
                {
                    if (PortsCB.Text == "" && BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port and baudrate", "red"); }
                    else if (PortsCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port", "red"); }
                    else if (BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a baudrate", "red"); }
                }
                catch (System.FormatException)
                {
                    if (PortsCB.Text == "" && BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port and baudrate", "red"); }
                    else if (PortsCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port", "red"); }
                    else if (BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a baudrate", "red"); }
                }
            }
            else if (Device.IsOpen == true)
            {
                WriteToConsole("Disconnected!!", "green");
                Device.Close();
                ConnectButton.Text = "Connect";
                BaudRateCB.Enabled = true; ;
                PortsCB.Enabled = true;
                DataMenu.Enabled = false;
                ConsoleLogs.Clear();
                PositionGraph.Series["gyroX"].Points.Clear();
                PositionGraph.Series["gyroY"].Points.Clear();
                ChartCounter = 0;
            }
        }



        string recivedData;


        //List<double> time = new List<double>();
        void Parachute_Status(string data)
        {
            int intData = int.Parse(data);
            switch (intData)
            {
                case 1:
                    parachute1_Status.Text = "Not triggered";
                    parachute2_Status.Text = "Not triggered";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    parachute1_Status.Text = "Triggered";
                    parachute2_Status.Text = "Not triggered";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    parachute1_Status.Text = "Not triggered";
                    parachute2_Status.Text = "Triggered";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    parachute1_Status.Text = "Triggered";
                    parachute2_Status.Text = "Triggered";
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void dataRecived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                recivedData = Device.ReadLine();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "hata");

            }


            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ProcessData));
        }

        int ChartCounter;
        private void gyroChart(string gyroDataX, string gyroDataY)
        {
           while (Device.IsOpen == true)
            {
                ChartCounter++;
                PositionGraph.Series["gyroX"].Points.AddXY(double.Parse(gyroDataX), ChartCounter);
                PositionGraph.Series["gyroY"].Points.AddXY(double.Parse(gyroDataY), ChartCounter);
            }
        }
        private void ProcessData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                
                string[] splitted_data = recivedData.Split('/');
                //gyroChart(splitted_data[0], splitted_data[1]);
                WriteToConsole(recivedData, "red");
                //irtifa_Box.Text = splitted_data[0];
                //GPS_Box.Text = splitted_data[1];
                //Enlem_Box.Text = splitted_data[2];
                //Boylam_Box.Text = splitted_data[3];
                /*YGPS_Box.Text = splitted_data[4];
                YEnlem_Box.Text = splitted_data[5];
                YBoylam_Box.Text = splitted_data[6];
                KGPS_Box.Text = splitted_data[7];
                KEnlem_Box.Text = splitted_data[8];
                KBoylam_Box.Text = splitted_data[9];
                JiroskopX_Box.Text = splitted_data[0];
                JiroskopY_Box .Text = splitted_data[1];
                JiroskopZ_Box .Text = splitted_data[12];
                gyroChart(JiroskopX_Box.Text, JiroskopY_Box.Text);
                İvmeX_Box.Text = splitted_data[13];
                İvmeY_Box.Text = splitted_data[14];
                İvmeZ_Box.Text = splitted_data[15];
                Aci_Box.Text = splitted_data[16];
                CRC_Box.Text = splitted_data[17];
                Parachute_Status(splitted_data[18]);
                Heat_Box.Text = splitted_data[19]; 
                */

            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException)
            {
                WriteToConsole("error", "red");
                return;
            }
            catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                WriteToConsole("error", "red");
                return;
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
            {
                WriteToConsole("error", "red");
                return;
            }
        } //Evde dock sistemlerine bak ve arayüz gelişimi için açık sayfalara bak
    }

}

            string[] splitted_data = recivedData.Split('/');
            //gyroChart(splitted_data[0], splitted_data[1]);
            WriteToConsole(recivedData, "red");
            //irtifa_Box.Text = splitted_data[0];
            //GPS_Box.Text = splitted_data[1];
            //Enlem_Box.Text = splitted_data[2];
            //Boylam_Box.Text = splitted_data[3];
            /*YGPS_Box.Text = splitted_data[4];
            YEnlem_Box.Text = splitted_data[5];
            YBoylam_Box.Text = splitted_data[6];
            KGPS_Box.Text = splitted_data[7];
            KEnlem_Box.Text = splitted_data[8];
            KBoylam_Box.Text = splitted_data[9];
            JiroskopX_Box.Text = splitted_data[0];
            JiroskopY_Box .Text = splitted_data[1];
            JiroskopZ_Box .Text = splitted_data[12];
            gyroChart(JiroskopX_Box.Text, JiroskopY_Box.Text);
            İvmeX_Box.Text = splitted_data[13];
            İvmeY_Box.Text = splitted_data[14];
            İvmeZ_Box.Text = splitted_data[15];
            Aci_Box.Text = splitted_data[16];
            CRC_Box.Text = splitted_data[17];
            Parachute_Status(splitted_data[18]);
            Heat_Box.Text = splitted_data[19]; 


this part shouldn't really have any commenting. for testing i decided to comment them
also i believe is the code block that causes the error since this part is supposed to write data to textBox etc.
i cant give the error since i am Turkish and gives the main error in Turkish
i tried changing the baudrate but didnt work and since it was only idea i got stuck

In with method do you have an error?

WriteToConsole() is a memory leak when it keeps appending text.  Works at first, but then just grinds to a halt when appending and painting the text takes longer than receiving it.  And eventually consumes too much memory.
You'll have to throw some of it away sometimes.

You have a dataRecived method, that presumably should listen to the DataReceived  event, but I cannot see this being attached anywhere. You will also need to consider threading, data should be read from a background thread, and this should be posted to the UI thread using Control.BeginInvoke (or one of the equivalent methods).

@JonasH dataRecived part is actually connected to ProcessData which does the heavy lifting and is a background thread(to my very limited thread knowledge). I am very new to the treading at the moment but i am still trying to learn. But also can you explain little more i think i didn't get what you mean

You might want to take a look at some examples online. The documentation contains a fairly complete console based example. I would also recommend doing some studying about thread safety and its potential hazards before doing anything involving multiple threads. It is fairly easy to make mistakes if you do not know about the hazards.

using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ArduinoSerial_Teknofest_
{
    public partial class ArduinoSerial : Form
    {
        private SerialPort Device = new SerialPort();

        public ArduinoSerial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Device.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        }

        private async void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Device.IsOpen)
            {
                string SelectedBaudRate = BaudRateCB.Text;
                string SelectedPort = PortsCB.Text;
                
                try
                {
                    Device.BaudRate = int.Parse(SelectedBaudRate);
                    Device.PortName = SelectedPort;
                    Device.Open();

                    if (Device.IsOpen)
                    {
                        ConnectButton.Text = "Disconnect";
                        BaudRateCB.Enabled = false;
                        PortsCB.Enabled = false;
                        DataMenu.Enabled = true;

                        WriteToConsole("Connected", "green");

                        // Start reading data asynchronously
                        await Task.Run(() => StartReadingData());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteToConsole($"Error: {ex.Message}", "red");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Device.Close();
                ConnectButton.Text = "Connect";
                BaudRateCB.Enabled = true;
                PortsCB.Enabled = true;
                DataMenu.Enabled = false;
                ConsoleLogs.Clear();
                PositionGraph.Series["gyroX"].Points.Clear();
                PositionGraph.Series["gyroY"].Points.Clear();
            }
        }

        private async Task StartReadingData()
        {
            while (Device.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    string receivedData = await Device.ReadLineAsync();
                    ProcessData(receivedData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteToConsole($"Error reading data: {ex.Message}", "red");
                }
            }
        }

        private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // This event will be raised when new data is received,
            // but we'll handle data reading asynchronously
        }

        private void ProcessData(string data)
        {
            // Process and update UI with received data
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => WriteToConsole(data, "red")));
            // Update other UI elements as needed
        }

        private void WriteToConsole(string message, string color)
        {
            // Write message to console
            ConsoleLogs.SelectionColor = Color.FromName(color);
            ConsoleLogs.SelectedText += $"/// {message}{Environment.NewLine}";
        }
    }
}

In this code:
The ConnectButton_Click event handler now starts reading data asynchronously using StartReadingData() method when the device is successfully connected.
The StartReadingData method continuously reads data from the serial port asynchronously using ReadLineAsync() method.
The DataReceivedHandler event handler is called whenever new data is received from the serial port. In this case, it is just a placeholder as we're handling data reading asynchronously.
The ProcessData method processes the received data and updates the UI. It is invoked asynchronously using BeginInvoke to update the UI controls from a non-UI thread.
The WriteToConsole method is used to write messages to the console with the specified color.

sorry but its gives the The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task' error for this line await Task.Run(() => StartReadingData());  and for this string receivedData = await Device.ReadLine(); gives the 'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? error

Sorry can you try this one
private async void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Device.IsOpen)
    {
        string SelectedBaudRate = BaudRateCB.Text;
        string SelectedPort = PortsCB.Text;
        
        try
        {
            Device.BaudRate = int.Parse(SelectedBaudRate);
            Device.PortName = SelectedPort;
            Device.Open();

            if (Device.IsOpen)
            {
                ConnectButton.Text = "Disconnect";
                BaudRateCB.Enabled = false;
                PortsCB.Enabled = false;
                DataMenu.Enabled = true;

                WriteToConsole("Connected", "green");

                // Start reading data asynchronously
                await StartReadingData(); // No need for Task.Run() here
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToConsole($"Error: {ex.Message}", "red");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Device.Close();
        ConnectButton.Text = "Connect";
        BaudRateCB.Enabled = true;
        PortsCB.Enabled = true;
        DataMenu.Enabled = false;
        ConsoleLogs.Clear();
        PositionGraph.Series["gyroX"].Points.Clear();
        PositionGraph.Series["gyroY"].Points.Clear();
    }
}

private async Task StartReadingData()
{
    while (Device.IsOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            string receivedData = await Device.ReadLineAsync();
            ProcessData(receivedData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToConsole($"Error reading data: {ex.Message}", "red");
        }
    }
}

